# installing gazebo 3.0 from source... "cannot open shared object" error

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I've made numerous attempts to get around this issue... read all similar past queries, but I'm completely new to linux so I have absolutely no idea how to interpret some of the answers

so, in the instructions (http://gazebosim.org/wiki/3.0/install), step 10, you're told to execute "gazebo", I end up with:

gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: libgazebo_common.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

during cmake, the installation path was shown as: /home/derek/gazebo_source/gazebo/build

it said to take note of this, so I did.  I then came upon instructions later about installation to local directories and such,

```
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<install_path>/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PATH=<install_path>/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=<install_path>/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

I tried every variation of replacing the <install_path> with the one designated by the cmake output, but to no avail... then, at the end of the instructions, you get this:

```
echo '/usr/local/lib' | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gazebo.conf 
sudo ldconfig
```

again, I don't really know what /usr/local/lib (i understand that this is where user files go, but as far as relating this to the GUI directory of /home/USER/gazebo etc) means, I tried every combination of prefixes that I could think of

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6307/installing-gazebo-3.0-from-source...-%22cannot-open-shared-object%22-error/) by [idhamb](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/813/idhamb/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-05-29**:
If you have run cmake with the proper CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX pointing to /usr the libraries should end up with the libraries on /usr/lib/... and don't need to use ldconfig at all.

**Comment by [idhamb](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/813/idhamb/) on 2014-05-29**:
this will be a last resort if i cant find a solution for the current installation, but will definitely give it a go tonight if i cant resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

when running the

```
echo '/usr/local/lib' | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/gazebo.conf 
sudo ldconfig
```

command make sure you change `'/usr/local/lib'` to where your gazebo libraries are, do a `$ locate libgazebo` in the terminal to find out where they are.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2014-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [idhamb](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/813/idhamb/) on 2014-05-29**:
i typed in "locate libgazebo" into a terminal, doesn't return anything... i tried a variety of 'search' and 'find' commands i found on the web to ID the correct path, nothing works :/

**Comment by [idhamb](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/813/idhamb/) on 2014-05-29**:
tried $locate libgazebo, said "libgazebo not found", tried $locate libgazebo_common.so.3, same thing :/

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-05-29**:
find /usr -name libgazebo*

**Comment by [idhamb](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/813/idhamb/) on 2014-05-29**:
success! thank you Jose, thank you Andrei!